# assign int[][] to int**

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

As far as I know, in some contexts, an array is converted into a pointer to its first element:

```
int a[5];
int * p;

p = a;
```

Following this approach and considering I can assign an array to a pointer, why can't I assign a bidimensional array to a pointer to a pointer?

```
int a[5][5];
int ** q;

q = a;
```

However, I can assign an array of pointers to a pointer to a pointer:

```
int * p[5];
int ** q;

q = p;
```

If an array is converted into a pointer to its first element, when q = a happens in the second example, a should be a pointer to a[0] and a[0] should be a pointer to a[0][0], right?

Besides, I don't get an error if I do:

```
cout << **a;
```

Thanks in advance and I hope you can help me to understand.

Comment: An array is not a pointer (it decays to it in some contexts _ namely function calls). Similarly a 2D array is not a pointer to a pointer. And a 2D array is not an array of pointers, those are different too

Comment: You cannot assign it, because you are not only doing the assignment to a variable but you are also allocating memory of size[5][5]. The way you allocate memory to pointer of pointer or int **q is different. You first allocate memory like this: int **q = new int *[5]; for(int i= 0; i < 5; i++){q[i] = new int[5];}

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that an array `int a[5][5];` stores 25 consecutive `int`.

A pointer to arrays/pointers like `int **q;` expects to find an array of consecutive pointers to `int`.

This is why the assignment you want to do is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

a multi-dimensional array can be assigned to a single pointer

```
int a[5][5];
int *p = a;
```

because the memory is allocated as a single block organized by row.

```
a = a11 a12 a13
    a21 a22 a23    

a = a11 a12 a13 a21 a22 a23
```

Answer (score 1):

For multidimensional arrays if you want to point into single (scalar) value, then you should use the following declarations:

```
int a[5][5];
int (*q)[5]; /* pointer to five-element array of basic type int */

q = a;
q[0][0]; /* equivalent to a[0][0] */
```

where `5` is the "column" size (next to left-most "row" size). In general for more dimensions remember that rule is that only left-most size is replaced with `(*q)` part of declarator.

In fact when you write function, that has multidimensional array parameter, then for compiler it's considered as in above form, for instance:

```
int foo(int a[5][5]) { ... }
```

is effectively replaced with:

```
int foo(int (*a)[5]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

For it would be more clear let's consider your first example

```
int a[5];
int * p;

p = a;
```

In can be rewritten the following way

```
T a[5];
T * p;

p = a;
```

where T is some type.

What is a two-dimensional array in C/C++? It is an array elements of which in turn are one-dimensional arrays.

So this definition

```
int a[5][5];
```

can be rewritten as

```
T a[5];
```

where T has type `int[5]`

And we have

```
T a[5];
T * p;

p = a;
```

where T as we already know is `int[5]` So p has type of pointer to array of type `int[5]` and has to be defined as

```
int ( *p )[5];

p = a;
```

`int ( * )[5]` and `int **` are two different types.

As for this code

```
int * p[5];
int ** q;

q = p;
```

when here T is `int *` so p is defined as `T *p`  that in turn is `int **p`